# Error in SQL query on Adventure Work database

Tags: sql-server-2008, adventureworks

I am looking for a solution to the problem from **Beginning Microsoft SQL Server® 2008 Programming** book.(AdventureWorks database used)

Ques> Show the most recent five orders that were purchased from account numbers that have spent more than $70,000 with AdventureWorks.

I found a solution to this on [See query](https://www.assignmentexpert.com/homework-answers/programming-and-computer-science/databases-sql-oracle-ms-access/question-182600) but this is not working. What's the error in this query?

```
SELECT ss.AccountNumbeR, OrderDate
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader ss
WHERE ss.TotalDue > 70000
AND ss.AccountNumber NOT IN (SELECT TOP 5 ss.AccountNumber
            FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail so
            JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader ss
            ON SO.SalesOrderID = ss.SalesOrderID
            HAVING SUM(so.LineTotal > 70000))
GROUP BY ss.TotalDue, ss.AccountNumber, OrderDate 
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm not entirely sure why you though this query *would* work:**

It's querying for orders where the account number is *not* in the top 5 which is the opposite of what we want, moreover `TOP 5` here has no ordering so it's entirely random. And this is entirely in the wrong place, the question wants the top 5 orders, not the top 5 accounts.

It's also filtering for orders where each of the orders individually has a value greater than 70000. And `HAVING SUM(so.LineTotal > 70000)` is a syntax error.

**I would advise you instead to use window functions here**

```sql
SELECT s.AccountNumber, s.OrderDate
FROM (
    SELECT so.*,
        TotalPerAccount = SUM(ss.LineTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY so.AccountNumber),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY so.AccountNumber ORDER BY so.OrderDate DESC)
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader so
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail ss ON so.SalesOrderID = ss.SalesOrderID
) s
WHERE s.TotalPerAccount > 70000
  AND s.rn <= 5;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=7ccecd20f67d118855b6dd369a6387e0)